# Local site testing with BrowserStack and self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, browserstack

I have started looking into testing our site with BrowserStack.
However, I'm having issues with live-testing (as opposed to automated testing with Selenium, which mostly works fine) a site we're developing as we're serving it with a self-signed certificate.

Manually approving the certificate doesn't bother me as much as the fact that some Ajax request are failing (at least on IE10) due to security issues and this makes it impossible to actually manually test the site.

An acceptable solution would be to somehow add our self-signed cert. into the list of trusted root CAs. However, I haven't found out how to upload files into the BrowserStack test environment (not sure if that's even possible, really).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**April 2021 update:**

BrowserStack has shipped a toggle to trust self-signed certs.

It is available on iOS and Android devices for now.

[image: self-signed cert browserstack]

Comment: This should become the accepted answer. We were struggling with an insecure certificate a lot while using it via iOS and Android, having this toggle enabled meant that all our issues went away. On top of that, we are using an extra flag in Selenium tests to accept insecure certificates: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/xcuitest/accept-insecure-certificates

Comment: I'm unable to find this option for certain versions of Mac OS Safari. (Mac OS Big Sur Safari 14.1)

Comment: Now available on most devices.

Answer (score 15):

I contacted BrowserStack about this issue, and their formal response is:
"We currently do not support installing client certificates on the remote machines. However, this is on our list, and we’ll keep you posted."

Hopefully this issues will be resolved soon and I'll post a different answer here.

Comment: I've actually haven't been following BrowserStack for a while , so no.

Comment: Three years ago? Yeesh.

Comment: So in 2015, it sounded like they were going to support it, but seems like now it's off their list: "Installing custom certificates on the remote machines on BrowserStack is not supported due to security concerns. However, I have noted down your request and we will be sure to keep you posted if there are any developments."

Comment: It's 2020 and problem is still there, but now you can't even bypass it by clicking "proceed to site anyway" as it's simply not there anymore in some browsers

Answer (score 5):

When it happens, open the "Network" tab, and open in a new tab the request which is failing. If it is "just" a certificate issue, you would then be able to bypass the warning. Then, your request should work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When the "Cannot Verify Server Identity" dialogue pops up, click details, then 'Trust'. This will work if all calls are to the same domain as the website.

Comment: This is fine, but the problem is that a lot of sites are built on multiple domain environments (for static content etc.) - so that will not work on all browser